# Separating business logic layer and security logic layer

Tags: .net, security, business-logic

I've been reading about claims based authentication and I understand that it is a great practice to separate the authentication, authorization and business layer from each other. We should have a component that authenticates, a component that checks authorization and is separate from authenticator and we also have a business logic layer. All of that makes sense except one part. Imagine a case where we have a product like youtube but users can only see the vides of the people they subscribe to and subscription needs approval. Now, how can that separate authorization component decide wether to allow getting a video or not without having access to database? this is not something we can put in a claim. The only way is to see if the requested video id is among the allowed (subscribed) videos.

Should I put these checks in business logic or access database in my authorization component?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on whether it is a business rule, you might indeed put it in your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dependency Injection principals the Authorization component does not need to have access to the business database, just an injected capability of delegating out a "Is this operation authorized" query. So in psuedocode;

```
class Authorization()
{
     public enumCheckAccessResult IsAuthorized(IIdentity userIdentity, ISecurable itemToCheckForAccess IAuthorizationExtension extension)
     {
          enumCheckAccessResult result = checkMyLocalAuthorisationStore(userIdentity, itemToCheckForAccess);
          if(result == enumAccessCheckResult.SecurableNotFound)
          {
               result = extension.CheckExternalAuthorisationStore(userIdentity, itemToCheckForAccess)
          }
     }
}
```

In my pseudocode the Authorisation class accepts an extension point (dependeny injection) of an IAuthorizationExtension instance, which can be provided by any consumer of the authorisation class. Note that we only use this extension if our own local store cant find the securable (i.e. item to be security checked)so the author of the IAuthorisationExtension cannot override the decision of my Authorisation class - if my Authorisation class says "access denied" we dont then consult the extension.